# How to do function override in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I've read the entire chapter about modules on this [book](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2019sp/textbook/modules/intro.html) but there's something I didn't understand.

Suppose I have a signature and an implementation of that signature:

```
module type X = sig
  val x : int
  val y : int
end

module X1 : X = struct
  let x = 5;
  let y = 6;
end
```

Then suppose I have a functor that has this signature as paremeter:

```
module IncX (M: X) = struct
  let x = M.x + 1
end
```

What if I want to instantiate `IncX` using the already defined `X1` module but override the `y` function?

I want to do something like this:

```
module X1_Specialized : X = struct
  //how use x from X1 module here?
  let y = 10;
end
```

The analog in OOP languages would be to override a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask for is usually called implementation inheritance. And it's not necessary to use a functor for this, just [include](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2019sp/textbook/modules/includes.html):

```
module X1_Specialized : X = struct
  include X1
  let y = 10
end
```

`include` will include the entire contents of `X1`, as if you had written its definition in place of the `include`. This includes a definition of `y`, but the following definition of `y` will shadow it, and essentially replace it.

Also note that OCaml doesn't use semicolon as a statement terminator. These are syntax errors in your code.